# JQuery $this selector - how to make it work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I am having trouble with $this selector for JQuery. This is doing nothing. The fundamental core of the script is not failing though.

```
$(this).css("background-image", 
"url(http://www.divethegap.com/update/z-images/diving-trips/tabs/bases-z.png)");
```

Any ideas why it does not work? I have tried the same effect using class.

THE FULL CODE (as requested)
http://jsfiddle.net/mcxez/1/:

Markup:

```
<a href="?accommodation" style="background-position:-15px top;" 
   onclick="inload('?accommodation'); return false">Accommodation</a>

<a href="?travel" style="background-position:-15px top;" 
   onclick="inload('?travel'); return false">Travel</a>
```

js:

```
function inload(thelink) {
    $('.TABbase').click(function(){
        $(this).css("background-image", 
            "url(http://www.divethegap.com/update/z-images/diving-trips/tabs/bases-z.png)"); 
    });

  return false;
}
```

Comment: what "$(this)" refers to depends on the context of the code. What comes before the code above?

Comment: [More about `this` at MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this)

Comment: JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mcxez/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the revised HTML

```
<a href="?accommodation" style="background-position:-15px top;" data-href="?accomodation" class="my_class">Accommodation</a>
<a class="my_class" href="?travel" style="background-position:-15px top;" data-href="?travel" >Travel</a>
```

Here is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".my_class").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(http://www.divethegap.com/update/z-images/diving-trips/tabs/bases-z.png)");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

in jQuery, `this` is normally a reference to something within a function.. like...

**HTML**

```
<button id="button1">1</button>
<button id="button2">2</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    alert( $(this).attr('id') ); //either 'button1' or 'button2'
}
```

In this case, `this` refers to the button being clicked.

Perhaps you can share some more code as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you calling `this` from? `this` is a special variable that refers to the object currently being referenced in a method that applies to it. If you're referencing `this` from outside of a method, it refers to the dom window. For example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
alert($(this)); // refers to window

$('body').bind('click', function() {
    alert($(this)); // refers to the jQuery object created by selecting the body element.
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For $(this) to work (or this) it must be relevant to an element. For example :

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert($(this).html());return false">test</a>
```

or, inside a selector loop :

```
$('.someClass').each(function() {
   $(this).css('background-color','#333');
});
```